# How can I customize validation error messages when using automatic redirects?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Using `Laravel 5.8` and generated field names, I would like to know if it is possible to change the validation messages used programmatically.

At the moment I am using the automatic redirection method of validating in my controller:

```php
function processRequest(Request $request)
{
    $generated = session()->get('expected_field');
    $request->validate([
        'preset' => 'required',
        $generated => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

This works as expected, but the default error message results in

"The `{$generated}` field is required" and that's not useful.

I would like to do this without refactoring to a custom Request class.

Comment: with `{$generated}` you mean the value of that field right? for example "The mickey_mouse field is required"

Comment: Yes, It can be anything (it's a random field, basically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the "Custom Validation Attributes" in `resoures/lang/{lang}/validation.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Attributes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
| with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
| of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
|
*/

'attributes' => [],
```

Here, can set your own display values for various validation fields.

For example, if `session()->get('expected_field');` was `"first_name"`, but you wanted it to say `"First Name"`, you'd set:

```
'attributes' => [
  'first_name' => 'First Name',
  ...
]
```

in that array and you'd be golden. The validation message would display as:

> The First Name field is required.

You can also update the default message for each rule, in the "Validation Language Lines" section if you don't like the structure/wording of it.

-Edit-

`validate()` accepts a 2nd parameter, which is an array of validation messages. This can be customized to manipulate the string returned by `session()->get('expected_field');`, or omit it entirely in favour of a more generic error message:

```
$this->validate([
  $generated => 'required'
], [
  // $generated.'.required' => 'The '.ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $generated)).' field is required.'
  $generated.'.required' => 'The Anti-Spam field is required.'
]);
```

With this logic, the validation rule would trigger for whatever `$generated` is, but the message would be more generic, or a manipulation of `$generated`

Comment: The field is generated programatically, and thus language files are not a solution.

Comment: Is this just a case of there being too many options to define them in a lang file? If that's the case, what specifically is the issue with `The {$generated} field is required.` (using `first_name` as an example)? Is it just that `first_name` is not human readable and `First Name` is? Confused what your requirements are.

Comment: When the form is generated a random field is created (session based, honeypot-like, anti-spam concept) So for example, the form will generate a random field name using `uniqid()`, put it in the session, then on validation check for that field to pass validation. Every time the form is created, the field name changes.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. So it would be something like `The {uniqid()} field is required.`, and yeah, that makes no sense. Updating my answer; `validate()` can accept a custom message array, will demonstrate that.